# Why can't I put a aligned right TextView inside a TableView?

Tags: android, layout

In my layout, I really need to the TableView be the root view, but inside it I need very much a single TextView to be aligned to the right border of the screen, but I keep receiving the warning: Invalid layout param in a TableLayout: layout_alignParentRight   activity_main.xml

What should I do to have a aligned textview inside a TableView?

Comment: Can you please share your xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gravity` in `TableLayout`, Try to set  `android:gravity="right"` to `TextView`

Answer (score 1):

android:layout_alignParentRight="true" works fine for me if it's not working then check your parent try fill_parent on the parent or try moving it from it's parent layout hope this helps